# What indicated that order matters in this question?

Tags: probability, statistics

> A journalist from the local newspaper interviews a randomly selected group
> of 3 medal winners.
> (d) Find the exact probability that there is at least one gold medal winner in the group.

Background; International A-Level S1 June 2020 Q3. The question was about a contest where if you jump some distance, you get a medal. Further, 1/3 of those people who got a medal and jumped past a larger distance, got a gold medal. Therefore
$$P(G)=\frac{1}{3} \text{ and } P(G')=\frac{2}{3}$$
*within the set of people who already got a medal which is what part d) considers.

For the possible combinations to part d), I wrote out
$$\text{GG'G'}\\\text{GGG'}\\\text{GGG}$$
And thought that order in which G or G' in the first two combinations was placed was irrelevant, because, when you pick a group of 3, as long as there is one person with gold, then it doesn't matter where that person "stands" in the order; the important bit is just that they are *there*.

But the MS takes into account the order. Well, they do $$1-P(\text{G'G'G'})$$
which is a lot easier, yes... but I want to know, given that I'm writing out all the combinations,

> What indication is there in the question that involved taking into account order?

*part d) is copied word-to-word from the past paper; that is all that is asked.

Comment: Try a simpler question: if you twice throw an unbiased coin then what is the probability on at least one head? Respecting order we have *equiprobable* outcomes HH,HT,TH,TT. Handsomely leading to outcome 3/4. If we do not respect order then we have 3 outcomes which are *not equiprobable*. You can do it like that but are forced to find the probabilities of the 3 outcomes separately (1/4,2/4 and 1/4). Cumbersome and error-prone.

Comment: @StinkingBishop, because there are $3\choose 1$ ways to choose which one of the three Bernoulli trials reaps the outcome associated with the probability 1/3

Comment: @drhab Somehow, I associate the flipping coins scenario easily with order like HT and TH but that does not come to mind for this specific question. Maybe its just conditioning after seeing the coin scenario many times over...

After thinking it over, the way I am seeing it is that, since all those other combinations also "just include 1 G in GG'G' ", then all are equivalent and their probabilities should be summed by my same logic.

Comment: You are free to do it the way you like (with or without order). In many cases though it is just very handsome practicize and respect an order. If the question does not directly provides one (e.g. simultaneous tossings, or the situation described in your answer) then you can just built one yourself. It never harms and often makes things more easy to handle. This because often it creates equiprobability.

Answer (score 1):

$P(G',G',G')$ is the probability all three didn't win gold. The event $\{G',G',G'\}$ is order independent; reordering three non-Gold winning statuses among three players still makes them three non-Gold winners, the same event.

---

Update: As suggested, the above is sloppy notation, intended for heuristic purposes. And a notion of "ordering" is not necessary. To write it in terms of Bernoulli trials, letting $X_i$ denote the random variable given by the indicator for person $i$ winning gold, then the set
$(\cap_i\{\omega:X_i(\omega)=0\})^c$ is the same as $\cup_i\{\omega:X_i(\omega)=1\}$ by De Morgan's laws.

Comment: Yes, I see how G'G'G' is order-independent. But I was asking for something like GG'G' which is order-dependent. But in any case, I think I got the idea; by my own logic G'GG' and G'G'G also satisfies "There is 1 Gold and 2 Non-Golds and that there is 1 Gold that is *just there* as well". Hence, it is really 3 times P(GG'G'). In any case, I should stick to Bernoulli trials!

Comment: Right, so $\{G',G,G'\}$ and $\{G',G',G\}$ are different events---they represent different people among the three who won gold (I think this is what you meant by different ordering).  However, the two events are equiprobable.

Comment: Formally $\{G',G',G'\}$ denotes a set with exactly one element (which is $G'$). So it is invalid as notation for event you described.

Comment: @drhab, yes, this was admittedly an abuse of notation.  Writing it in terms of Bernoullis would have been better